# eslint-plugin-react-hooks is giving unexpected errors (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app, eslint

I have an issue where my vscode eslint is giving me wrong warnings. I have a simple function in react component which I am trying to optimize with useCallBack hook.

Here is the simple function where I am getting two props and there are being used in params object I create and as per the documentation, I am putting those two props as dependencies of useCallBack.

```
const Test = ({ ReportAddressNumber, ClientNumber }) => {
const [test, setTest] = useState({ count: 0 });
const fetchSampleIDs = useCallback(() => {
  setTest(true);
  const URL = `/Samples`;
  const params = {
    ReportAddressNumber,
    ClientNumber,
  };

  fetch(URL, params)
}, [ClientNumber, ReportAddressNumber]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchSampleIDs();
}, [fetchSampleIDs]);

 return <h1>{test.count}</h1>;
};
```

Now the issue is in vscode it's telling me that those two props are unnecessary as dependencies in useCallback.

```
React Hook useCallback has unnecessary dependencies: 'ClientNumber' and 'ReportAddressNumber'. Either exclude them or remove the dependency array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

[image]

I am able to reproduce this with my `.eslintrc` and `package.json` file. I have created this codesandbox to play with this and in order to see the actual issue, you need to export the codesanbox as zip and run `npm install` and look at it in vscode.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-mahavira-fvsub

I am appreciating your knowledge and contribution here, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After spending 4 hours finally I got the answer.

There is a conflicting dependency. I am using `eslint-config-airbnb: 16.1.0` which does not include any react-hooks linting configurations. However, I had installed the `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` on my own which was conflicting with `eslint-config-aribnb` versions.

upgrading `eslint-config-airbnb` as per instruction fixes my issue.
In case if anyone have same issue.